# How do I force a redraw using python in gtk3?

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3

Apparently, in Gtk3 the 'expose' event/signal is replaced with the 'draw' signal.

How do I force a redraw using python in Gtk3? I was not able to find any window invalidation function.

Comment: This should be moved to https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`widget.queue_draw()`

It is the same as in GTK+ 2.x.